# Use a checkbox to toggle a Jquery UI event

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I want to be able to run the jquery UI effect on this page:

http://jqueryui.com/toggle/

but when the user ticks or unticks a checkbox rather than clicking a button. I only want the one effect so I don't need the selection box. Basically I want some form fields to slide in or out depending on if the user checks or unchecks the checkbox.

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried? Please post that.

Comment: none, I don't know where to start to make the checkbox the toggle instead of the button

Comment: ok so now I've got to this http://jsfiddle.net/rHENX/ but now the checkbox won't tick. It stays unticked when clicking it, but the slide works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've adapted the code from the jQuery UI and made this JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/m5sTY/13/

You can just add a click even to the the checkbox and see if it's checked:

```
$( "#effect" ).toggle( false );
$("#run_effect").click(function(){
    if($('#run_effect').is(':checked')){
        runEffect();
        //you can do something else if the checkbox is checked here
    }else{
        runEffect();
        //you can do something else if the checkbox is unchecked here
    }
});
```

I removed the return false and it works fine. Try that.

Comment: Seems to have the same issue that the box won't check

Comment: @guru I updated my answer. The return false was causing the checkbox to not be selected.

Comment: perfect works great. Just a follow up question, how do I make it not visable as default and ticking the box makes it appear?

Comment: You could set it to false before you execute it. Now this doesn't hide that space but it should give you an idea. I updated my answer and JS fiddle.

Comment: I'd also look into .show/.hide/.animate as alternative ways to do this.

Comment: Ok now my question is why does it work in jsFiddle and when I make a html page exactly the same it doesn't work?
http://www.mrmobile.net.au/test1.html